# AS3 Error #1009 in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This error pops up:

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. 
at test9_fla::MainTimeline/PlayerMovement()
```

Here is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayerMovement); 

function PlayerMovement(event:Event) {      

    if(down) {
        Jack.y += speed;
        if(Jack.hitTestObject(Muur1))
        {
            Jack.y -= speed;
        }}else if(up)
    {
        Jack.y -= speed;
        if(Jack.hitTestObject(Muur1))
        {
            Jack.y += speed;
        }}else if(left)
    {
        Jack.x -= speed;
        if(Jack.hitTestObject(Muur1))
        {
            Jack.x += speed;
        }}else if(right)
    {
        Jack.x += speed;
        if(Jack.hitTestObject (Muur1))
        {
            Jack.x -= speed;
        }}
```

How could I solve the error?

Comment: Run it through the debugger and see exactly where the problem is. It's probably because one of the variables used is not initiated.

Comment: @Feia because `down` is not defined

Comment: -1 for absolutely terrible looking code. I had a hard time telling that there was an if statement with three else-if's. Also, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `stage` is not defined and you need to wait for the onAddedToStage event. But why are you accessing the stage directly anyway? You don't need to, you can simply add your event listener to the current movie clip (which in your case is most likely the document root).

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayerMovement);
```

Comment: Since it's probably a game, it's generally a bad idea to have more than one ENTER_FRAME handler. Though it's better to completely ditch ENTER_FRAME for and use Timer events instead.